# JTable is only showing the first column of imported data. How do I show all columns?

Tags: java, csv, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I'm building a table of imported values from a csv sheet. I have 95 rows and 26 columns. I want to display all of the "dataS" values in my JTable, but I'm only getting the first column.

Is there something wrong with the way I store the data values?

Thanks!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;

public class mealBuilder {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File myObj = new File("NutrData.csv");
        Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
        ArrayList<String[]> records = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        String[] record = new String[2];

        while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
            record = myReader.nextLine().split(",");
            records.add(record);
        }

        String[] columnNames = new String[]{Arrays.toString(records.get(0))}

        Object[][] dataS = new Object[records.size()][records.get(0).length];

        for (int i = 0; i < records.size() - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < records.get(0).length - 1; j++) {
                dataS[i][j] = records.get(i)[j];
            }
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Meal-Builder");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JTable foodMenu = new JTable();
        foodMenu = new JTable(dataS, columnNames);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(foodMenu, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setSize(1400, 900);

        panel.setSize(700, 400);
        panel.setLocation(25, 25);
        foodMenu.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(600, 400));

        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `frame.setLayout(null);` -- ugh :(

Comment: How many columns are you expecting? Why the `- 1` here: `j < records.get(0).length - 1;`? And shouldn't the outer for loop be, `for (int i = 1; i < records.size(); i++) {`?

Comment: It would be so much simpler if you actually made use of a `TableModel`

Comment: You only have one column defined, `String[] columnNames = new String[]{Arrays.toString(records.get(0))}` <- This is create an array with a single element which is the concatenated contents of the first record :/

Answer (score 0):

Soo, two "core" issues.

## First...

```
String[] columnNames = new String[]{Arrays.toString(records.get(0))}
```

Is creating an array with a single element, which is the concatenated result of all the elements in `records.get(0)`

It should simply be...

```
String[] columnNames = records.get(0);
```

## Second...

```
for (int i = 0; i < records.size() - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < records.get(0).length - 1; j++) {
        dataS[i][j] = records.get(i)[j];
    }
}
```

is problematic for a number of reasons.  First, you're including the first row of results, which is actually the header values and in both loops, you're excluding the last element (`i < records.size() - 1`)

It should be more like...

```
for (int i = 1; i < records.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columnNames.length; j++) {
        dataS[i][j] = records.get(i)[j];
    }
}
```

## Supplementary...

`frame.setLayout(null);` is not doing you any favours, in fact, it's doing you a lot of harm.

In fact, I don't understand the need to use a second `JPanel` to contain the `JScrollPane` and the whole thing could be simplified to something like...

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Meal-Builder");

        JTable foodMenu = new JTable();
        foodMenu = new JTable(dataS, columnNames);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(foodMenu);

        frame.add(scroll);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: I had the -1 because my data was messed up and I didn't need the last row. But I just went back and edited it. 

But I have my whole table of data now. I just started learning java 3 months ago so I’m fumbling in the dark mostly. Much appreciate the feedback!